# Task management application that recommends you what task do next based on time available

Tags: project-management, todo

I'm been using Toodledo but price has changed and also it is not being improved.

I would like to know alternatives that have an Android, iOS and web version and that have this killer functionality:

It should recommend you what task to do next based on your time available and in the priority, deadline and duration of the tasks you have on your "backlog".